# generating COM object procedures from existing IDL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com

I'm creating new COM object using ATL. I must create dublicate COM object from one compiled version I have. To eliminate some boring job I would like to extract IDL information from original COM and apply it to existing one. In this case I expect to have code skeleton. Is it possible such kind of automatic generation c++ function description from IDL?

Comment: [`#import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6) can import the type library of interest and generate you interface classes to inherit from. Is it good enough, or you wanted something to be more helpful?

Comment: sounds great. But how to inherit from typelib? I'm new to c++.